# center a mapkit map on a country

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit

In my ipad app, i need to put a map of one country, so there are two parts in my question:
1: how to center the map on a country?
2: how to set the initial Scale of the map?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you are going to first need to find the Lat/Lon coordinates of a point somewhere in the center of the country. Let's say you have the following defined:

```
MKMapView *mapView;
float latitude_coordinate;
float longitude_coordinate;
float latMeters;
float lonMeters;


CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinates, latMeters, lonMeters)
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

latMeters/lonMeters are the number of meters wide and high for the region that the map will display.

Comment: The function should be `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` instead of `MKCoordinateRegionMake`.

Answer (score 1):

To get center coordinate of a country you can use geonames web service. For details check following question in stack overflow:

[Need a list of all countries in the world, with a longitude and latitude coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702309/need-a-list-of-all-countries-in-the-world-with-a-longitude-and-latitude-coordin)